# Cherrypy REST> TypeError: Chunk is not of type bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, cherrypy

I have problem view JSON data. View does not work.

500 Internal Server Error

The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 675, in respond
    response.finalize()
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 947, in finalize
    content = self.collapse_body()
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 911, in collapse_body
    repr(chunk))
TypeError: Chunk {'__type__': 'Anchor', 'code': 'AN2', 'fwver': '0.8', 'host': '10.10.10.105', 'hwver': '0.10', 'idanchor': '2b590a73-e7af-47a1-bee5-dc8dd854e86a', 'locgeog': '0101000020E6100000A541A070CA092D40C055CEC46F074940', 'name': 'V rohu vpravo od dveří', 'port': 12344, 'rtlsaddress': 'DECA013010000BD6'} is not of type 'bytes'
```

Comment: input have to str or bytes
        if isinstance(self.body, text_or_bytes):
            return self.body

        newbody = []
        for chunk in self.body:
            if six.PY3 and not isinstance(chunk, bytes):
                raise TypeError("Chunk %s is not of type 'bytes'." %
                                repr(chunk))
            newbody.append(chunk)
        newbody = ntob('').join(newbody)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that CherryPy is not been very friendly with that error, but basically the handler is expected to return `bytes` not a dictionary. For that you need to decorate the method with `@cherrypy.tools.json_out()`.

For more information: http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/basics.html?highlight=json#encoding-response